# Codeigniter route page using database value

Tags: codeigniter, routes

currently I have a page like the following - abc.com/controller/action/23 Here 23 is Item id,which is dynamic. I have to fetch the name of the item using the id from database and route to a new url like following - abc.com/itemname. How can I do that?

I tried this, but not working

controller code -

```
public function action($id,$url=NULL) {
    if($url==''){
        $getUrl=$this->Wishlist_model->getwishlistByid($id)->url;
        redirect(base_url(). 'controller/action/'.$id.'/'.$getUrl);
    }
    else{
        //load view
    }
}
```

route code -

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'wishlist/wishlist/$1/$2';
```

Comment: Show your code what you tried to do that?

Comment: @owais code added.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to some other function like this by setting the data to be displayed:

```
   $dataArr=array(
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>'ABC',
        'address'=>'XYZ'
    );
    $this->session->set_flashdata('item_data', $dataArr);
    redirect($itemname);
```

And for the url like 'abc.com/itemname' to handle, you need to put the following in your routes.php

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'controller/function';
```

Now in the **controller/function**, you can access all the data and display in your template like :

```
$data = $this->session->flashdata('item_data');
```

Let me know in case of queries or anything unclear